# Is it possible to combine SAML 2.0 SSO with session login of QR Code

Tags: saml, qr-code

I was wondering if it is possible to combine SAML 2.0 SSO with QR Code scanning or fundamentally it is not possible?

If a session exists in one device the user can scan it with her chell phone and login instantly. Something similar is found in applications like Discord, Viber etc.

Is it also safe or it has security drawbacks?